# DNA to Protein | translation incorrection

Tags: python, dictionary, text, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I had no error. Always refresh cache and local memory.

**Resources for Verifying Translations:**

[NCBI Protein Translation Tool][1] (Validation)

[Text Compare][2] (Verification)

[Solution Inspiration][3]

300 DNA chars -> 100 protein chars.

---

```
# dna_sequence = above sequence
```

```
dna_codons = {
    'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
    'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'*', 'TAG':'*',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'*', 'TGG':'W',
} # replaced '_' for '*'

output_protein = ''
for i in range(0, len(dna_sequence), 3):
  codon = dna_sequence[i:i+3]
  output_protein += dna_codons.get(codon,'')
    
print(output_protein)
```

**Example Problem & Solution:**
ps://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dna-protein-python-3/

Comment: The first issue I’m seeing is that your code doesn’t look for a start codon, it incorrectly starts translating at the first nucleotide. Your NCBI solution seems to be doing the same though, which is surprising. (Another thing: it’s unnecessary to truncate your DNA sequence length to a multiple of 3; omitting this step won’t change the result).

Comment: Ok, interesting insights. I would like my solution to translate the same way as NCBI. I won't need start codons, as really I'm translating entire sequences.

Comment: Anyway, I can’t reproduce the issue. Your code contains several errors which prevent it from executing (indentation, variable names not matching) but once these are fixed the output is identical to that from NCBI/EBI/…, except for `_` instead of `*`. So I really don’t understand where your alleged output is coming from.

Comment: Sorry I'll fix now

Comment: I'll have a look over my solution again and update this post asap

Comment: @KonradRudolph Interesting note: my 2 lines of conditioning length DID have an affect, but an incorrect one - with a separate sequence. Notice how my .get line exception handles by returning blank? This is for remainder 1-2 chars that aren't a key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with you mixing up variable names - your translation code appends to `protein` but you print `output_protein` which I assume is actually created somewhere else in your code(?). Also, you first edit the variable `dna_sequence` but iterate over `dna` which I assume is also defined elsewhere and maybe doesn't match `dna_sequence`.

After editing the variable names I can use your code to get the same translation as the NCBI tool.

```
dna_sequence = 'TTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTGCACTCACGCAGTATAATTAATAACTAATTACTGTCGTTGACAGGACACGAGTAACTCGTCTATCTTCTGCAGGCGCTTACGGTTTCGTCCGTGTTGCAGCCGATCATCAGCACATCTAGGTTTTGTCCGGGTGTGACCGAAAGGTAAGATGGAGAGCCTTGTCCCTGGTTTCAACGAGAAAACACACGTCCAACTCAGTTTGCCTGTTTTACAGGTTCGCGACGTGCTCGTACG'
# dna_sequence = above sequence
if len(dna_sequence ) % 3 == 2: dna_sequence = dna_sequence [:-2]
if len(dna_sequence ) % 3 == 1: dna_sequence = dna_sequence [:-1]

#%% 
dna_codons = {
    'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
    'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                 
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'*', 'TAG':'*',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'*', 'TGG':'W',
}

output_protein = ""
for i in range(0, len(dna_sequence), 3):
    codon = dna_sequence[i:i+3]
    output_protein += dna_codons.get(codon,'')

print(output_protein)

ncbi = 'L*ICSLNEL*NLCGCHSAACLVHSRSIINN*LLSLTGHE*LVYLLQALTVSSVLQPIISTSRFCPGVTER*DGEPCPWFQRENTRPTQFACFTGSRRART'
if ncbi == output_protein:
    print("Matches")
```

Comment: Sorry that's my horrible variable naming, when creating a minimal code sample. Code updated in post

Comment: Try running the code again as edited. If you're in an interactive environment try restarting the kernel and re-running. I do not think there is an issue with your translation code.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect this too, as you can @Konrad Rudolph have pointed out. Will do so now and update you asap

Comment: I was running in PyCharm. Restarted my PC and outputs appear the same. Thank you David Parry & @Konrad Rudolph. Sorry for inconvenience. I will update post as a useful tool for validating and verifying translations